# figure read speed access to a file from a process

Tags: linux, filesystems, process

**Background info for the request:**:

I have a radius server (freeradius running on Linux) that for each request needs to parse a long text file containing the allowed mac-address.
From time to time, it hangs.

Since the number of requests is quite high, I want to see if there's some bottleneck due to the read access of the file (I should check also the speed of the file-parsing, but for that, I know where to check: the source file).
So, I would like to monitor the read speed access of a process for a specific file, in order to figure if the process "hangs" due to the I/O limit.

**What I'm not interested in:**
a solution for the hang of radius or debugging radius itself.

**What I would like to know:**
a generic way to check, for a generic process, the read I/O on the disk when reads a specific file.

Thanks!

.: Francesco

Comment: What size of file are we talking about? You can check the `wa` value in `top` to see how much time the system spends waiting for I/O

Comment: 8 MB of a txt file. ~170k entries.

Comment: ... looks like it's time to switch to a proper database. Are you doing binary search? or simply parsing the whole file?

Comment: parsing the whole file, cannot switch to db

Comment: You would like to know about `iotop` try with `-o`, `-b` or others, while running anything, will give you information on what you ask.